# How to style drawer menu options in Android Studio - headers for group not stylizing

Tags: java, android, xml, menu, android-drawer

*[Edited 10/5/2023]*

I have a `drawer menu` - swipe the screen from the left and it appears with a list of menu headers each having beneath it 3-5 sub-menu items, each sub-menu item is clickable.  I cannot get the main header items to stand out - e.g. a different background color, different font size and different font color.  For a simple example, take the group header "Manage Songs" (`@+id/menu_item_manage_songs_header`) and sub-menu items being *Add New Songs*, *Edit Songs*, *Open Song*, *Search Song*

I wish to get the group header "Manage Songs" to stand out but cannot locate the file/code where this is currently taking place.  Here is `DrawerLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    tools:openDrawer="start">
    
    ...

    <!-- Navigation Drawer -->
    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
         />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here is my `drawer_menu.xml`:

```
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Header: Manage Songs -->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_manage_songs_header"
        android:title="Manage Songs"
        android:enabled="false"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/custom_header_layout"
        android:itemTextAppearance="@style/GroupHeaderStyle">
        <menu>
            <group android:id="@+id/group_songs">
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/menu_item_add_new_song"
                    android:title="Add New Song"
                    android:onClick="onNavigationItemSelected" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/menu_item_edit_songs"
                    android:title="Edit Songs"
                    android:onClick="onNavigationItemSelected" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/menu_item_open_song"
                    android:title="Open Song"
                    android:onClick="onNavigationItemSelected" />
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/menu_item_search_songs"
                    android:title="Search Songs"
                    android:onClick="onNavigationItemSelected" />
            </group>
        </menu>
    </item>
    ...

</menu>
```

Thank you in advance - this seems straight forward.
**This is what I have tried:**
(1) in my java page setting bg color

- declaring under class: `MenuItem GROUP_SONGS;`
- initializing in onCreate(): `GROUP_SONGS = (MenuItem) navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.menu_item_manage_songs_header);`
- trying to set values - I can change the text for the Title - this works: `GROUP_SONGS.setTitle("Changed [1]");`
- but this doesn't work: `GROUP_SONGS.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 20);` (I know
  that `setTextSize` is not part of the `MenuItem` class...)

(2) set the `style` in `themes.xml`

```
    <style name="GroupHeaderStyle">
        <item name="android:background">@color/light_orange</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">22sp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>
```

and calling this using `itemTextAppearance`:

```
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_manage_songs_header"
        android:title="Manage Songs"
        android:enabled="false"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:itemTextAppearance="@style/GroupHeaderStyle">
```

Answer (score 2):

The question is not very well understood but to perform actions on each of the menu items you will need to implement a listener.

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle 
    savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);
    }
  
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
   
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch(id){ 
    case R.id.search:
   //action
    break;
    }
    return true;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @Jordy!  I will need to edit my question for clarity.  I desire to `style` the `drawer menu` items - specifically the menu headers (not clickable) from the sub-menu items (each a clickable option).  However I integrated your feedback as I was using to call actions from the main menu: `onOptionsItemSelected()` as opposed to `onNavigationItemSelected()` which I changed, however without any impact upon the styling (e.g.: bg color, text size...) of my `drawer menu` headers.  Thank you again for your interest!